# Cannot convert list of tuples into a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples

I've been searching for a solution for hours, but I can't find anything that helps. I'm having a problem converting a list of tuples into a dictionary. I get this error: 'ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #320 has length 1; 2 is required.' Here is a small example of the list of tuples:

```
[('Heat_equation', 262), ('Portal:Tertiary_Educatio', 262), ('Help:Wiki_markup_example', 262), ('Quantum_mechanics', 262), ('IB_Language_A:_English_Language_and_Literature_Course_Materia', 261), ('Pulmonary_Plethor', 261)]
```

This is what I want:

```
{'Heat_equation': 262, 'Portal:Tertiary_Educatio': 262, 'Help:Wiki_markup_example': 262, 'Quantum_mechanics': 262, 'IB_Language_A:_English_Language_and_Literature_Course_Materia': 261, 'Pulmonary_Plethor': 261}
```

The length is 2 though right? I'm not sure why I'm getting an error. Here is the function where I'm trying to convert the list of tuples into a dictionary:

```
import urllib.request
import json
import re


def get_url(url):
    text = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read().decode()
    return text


def get_choice():
    try:
        print("Select from the following options or press <?> to quit:")
        print("1. Display top 1000 articles and views.")
        print("2. Display top 100 learning projects.")
        choice = input()
        choice = int(choice)
        if 1 <= choice <= 2:
            print()
            return choice
    except ValueError:
        if choice == "":
            return None
        print("%s is not a valid choice.\n" % choice)


def display_json(text):
    lst = []
    dictionary = json.loads(text)
    for item in dictionary['items']:
        for article in item['articles']:
            line = (article['article'], article['views'])
            lst.append(line)
        return lst


def convert_dict(lst):
    d = dict()
    [d[t[0]].append(t[1]) if t[0] in (d.keys())
     else d.update({t[0]: [t[1]]}) for t in lst]
    dictionary = {k: v[0] for k, v in d.items()}
    return dictionary


def display_dict(dictionary):
    print(dictionary)


def learning_project(dictionary):
    lst_2 = []
    for key, value in dictionary.items():
        string = str(key)
        match = re.findall(r'([^\/ ]+).*?\w+.*', string)
        match.append(value)
        tup = tuple(match)
        lst_2.append(tup)
    return lst_2


def convert(lst_2):
    p = dict(lst_2)
    print(p)


def main():
    while True:
        url = "https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/metrics/pageviews/top/en.wikiversity/all-access/2018/01/all-days"
        choice = get_choice()
        if choice == None:
            break
        elif choice == 1:
            text = get_url(url)
            lst = display_json(text)
            dictionary = convert_dict(lst)
            display_dict(dictionary)
        elif choice == 2:
            text = get_url(url)
            lst = display_json(text)
            dictionary = convert_dict(lst)
            lst_2 = learning_project(dictionary)
            convert(lst_2)


main()
```

To explain the learning project function, I had a bigger dictionary I needed to parse. So I turned the key into a string and parsed the key with RegEx. I then appended the value to the key and that created rows of lists. Then I turned the rows of lists into tuples, and created a list of tuples. Now I'm just trying to turn this back into a dictionary, but it is not working. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can pass the list of tuples to the dict constructor. `dict(my_list)`

Comment: You're creating a new dictionary with one element each time through the loop, not a dictionary with all the elements.

Comment: Isn't that the same thing as this line though? `d = dict(lst_2)`

Comment: I had similar error, problem was some of my tuples in the list were not length of 2 items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are getting errors with  `p = dict(lst_2)` then your input data is not compliant with your requirement.  You could make the conversion more robust by ensuring that list elements are always a two entry tuple.

```
p = dict( (*t,None,None)[:2] for t in lst_2 or [])
```

This will not fix the data but it may allow you to move forward and perhaps detect the faulty data by finding None key or None values in the resulting dictionary.

Comment: Thanks! This seems to work so far. If I wanted to print the first 5 items in the dictionary could I use this line of code, or would I need to fix the data thats causing the error? @Alain

Comment: The first 5 in the dictionary are going to be the first 5 in the list. so you could simply `print(lst_2[:5])` but I believe you should be looking for `p[None]` (which would mean there is an empty tuple in the list) or `print({ k:v for k,v in p.items() if v is None})` (which correspond to single value tuples in the list).  Even better would be to start from the list itself: `print([t for t in lst_2 if len(t) != 2])`

Answer (score 1):

```
data = [('Heat_equation', 262), ('Portal:Tertiary_Educatio', 262), 
        ('Help:Wiki_markup_example', 262), ('Quantum_mechanics', 262), 
        ('IB_Language_A:_English_Language_and_Literature_Course_Materia', 261), 
        ('Pulmonary_Plethor', 261)]
mydict = dict(data)
```

Comment: I tried that. I got the error: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Comment: @Will91099 No it should definitely work. If you are getting error `"NoneType' object is not iterable"` then you might be passing `None` type `object` to the `dict` method. Something like this `data= None`; `mydict=dict(data)`.

Comment: What's the difference between `d = dict(lst_2)` in my code and `mydict = dict(data)`? Because I still get  'ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #320 has length 1; 2 is required.'

Comment: My list contains over a thousand tuples so I cant copy and paste all the tuples into a list either. @mohammed

Comment: @Will91099 For converting a `list` of `tuple` into dict using `dict` method each `tuple` should contain two item ( It takes first item as `key` and second as `value`). `"'ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #320 has length 1; 2 is required.' "`  this error will raise if any one of the tuple contains only one item.

Comment: @Will91099 What you are trying to achieve in your function?

Comment: I'm trying to convert the list of tuples into a dictionary, but the tuples in my list have 2 items in it already, (or at least I think so) so I'm not sure why using `dict()` does not work. @mohammed

Comment: @Will91099 what you are trying to achieve here `match = re.findall(pattern, string)`. The problem is with the pattern. Some times the match carries None type object, then the tuple will contain only one item.

Comment: I changed it to `match = re.findall(r'([^\/ ]+).*?\w+.*', string)` but I still get the same error. I put in the entire code because maybe it's something else. Thanks for your help by the way. @mohammed